# Setting rails environment with Foreman

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, foreman

How do you set the rails environment with Foreman?

For example, if I wanted to run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` on my development machine, but I wanted to set the rails environment to production so I could see exactly how this process would run on the production server - I could do this using vanilla rails by doing `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`.

But how do I do this with Foreman? For example, I know I can do `bundle exec foreman run rake assets:precompile`, but that doesn't specify the rails environment as production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is [to use a `.env` file in your project's root directory](https://ddollar.github.io/foreman/#ENVIRONMENT). Inside that file, add this line:

```
RAILS_ENV=production
```

Now, anytime you run Foreman locally, it will set the rails environment to production. So, if you run `bundle exec foreman run rake assets:precompile`, the environment will be production for that task. Don't forget to change it back when you're done! ;-)